# T-SQL - only stuff / concatenate some columns and drop xml

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stuff

I have a table like this:

| ID | C1 | C2 | seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This is my re | ally long sentence | 1 |
| 1 | This is my re | stored in a | 2 |
| 1 | This is my re | really terrible format | 3 |

And I need some SQL query or stored procedure to pull it out such that it reads "this is my really long sentence stored in a really terrible format"

```
select 
    case 
       when seq = '1' 
          then c1 else '' 
    end + stuff((select c2 from table t2 
                 where t2. id = t1.id and t2.seq = t1.seq
                 for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') 
from 
    table t1
```

I've got this going but it's putting XML in and I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The for xml doesn't remove the XML like I thought, only leading chars, I had to cast c1 to an nvarchar resulting in an unnamed column and no xml :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

`FOR XML` will use the column name as a node name, so if you have

```sql
SELECT someCol
FROM tbl
FOR XML PATH('')
```

you will still get XML like this

```xml
<someCol>someValue</someCol>
```

The point of this concatenation trick is to get an unnamed column, so that there is no node name, just the values. So you just need to use *any* function or calculation on the value to remove the column name

In your case, `STUFF` is not necessary, because you have no separator.

Don't forget to use `, TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')` to prevent XML escaping/entitization.

```
select 
    c1 + (
        select case when 1=1 then c2 end
        from table t2 
        where t2.id = t1.id and t2.seq >= 2
        for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
from 
    table t1
where seq = '1';
```

---

Of course, if you are on SQL Server 2017+, you can just use `STRING_AGG`

```
select 
    c1 + string_agg(cast(c2 as nvarchar(max)), '')
from 
    table t1
group by t1.ID, t1.c1;
```